# When did "sci-fi" become popular?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

When did the term sci-fi come into usage?

Comment: It's always been around, but until the advent of big-time shows like _Star Trek/Wars_, the usual reference to science fiction was just ***SF***, pronounced /ɛsɛf/. Today _sci-fi_, pronounced /sayfay/, refers more to film, video, game, and comic genres of science fiction mythologies -- often mixed with fantasy indistinguishably -- while written science-fiction is still called _SF_, and distinguished (usually) from fantasy as a genre.

Comment: I remember reading an essay by someone like Asimov about the term (and it's history vs. SF etc); the guy was so prolific I have no idea where I might have seen it, but perhaps an introduction to a compilation?

Comment: I'm not sure how current it is, but among the fans who used to go to science fiction conventions and publish fanzines, _SF_ is what we read, and _Sci-Fi_, pronounced "skiffy", is what those-people-who-don't-know-any-better are interested in.

Answer (score 5):

According to [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sci-fi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csci%20-%20fi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsci%20-%20fi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSci%20-%20Fi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSci%20-%20fi%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Csci%20-%20fi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bsci%20-%20fi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSci%20-%20Fi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSci%20-%20fi%3B%2Cc0) it started increasing in popularity around 1965.

[image]

The OED online has a citation from 1954:

> 1954   Variety 17 Feb. 38/4   ‘Junior Science’, aside from its positive qualities, is a rewarding change of pace from the more thunderous sci-fi and spaceship packages.

And it notes that *sci-fic* and *S.F.* are earlier:

*S.F.*:

> 1929   Sci. Wonder Stories June 92/3   The S.F. Magazine. (Science-Fiction).
>
> 1948   G. Conklin Treas. Sci. Fiction p. ix,   Many SF writers are feeling the urgent need for social controls over our physical powers.

*sci-fic*:

> 1939   Le Zombie 18 Nov. 2   Popular Pubs does not now publish a sci-fic mag.
>
> 1952   J. Merril in Thrilling Wonder Stories Dec. 6/1   Does your science-fiction story taste different lately? Is the flat familiar stale taste disappearing?.. There's a reason. Its name is Synthesis, and sci-fic is its prophet.

Comment: The OED2 provides a 1955 citation from *Britannica Book of the Year* and a 1957 one from *MD Medical Newsmag*. I wouldn’t be surprised if they’ve found prior references since then.

Comment: @tchrist I've updated the answer to include some background.

Comment: Yes, I see; thanks. But alas, it won’t let me upvote again. :)